# Why does Curiosity have two images of itself on itself, or is one a QR-code?

Tags: mars, identify-this-object, rovers, curiosity

The first image in CNN"s [New images show Mars as you've never seen it before](https://edition.cnn.com/2019/09/20/world/mars-layers-dunes-scn/index.html) shows a partial "selfie" by the Curiosity rover which includes what looks like two images on the rover itself.

The one on the left appears to be a line drawing of itself, and the one on the right might be an abstraction of that, or a QR code, or something else. For similar looking 5x5 and 6x6 "space QR-codes" see answers to [Have “QR” or other 2D barcodes been used in spaceflight?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/31915/12102)

However that image also looks to me like an abstraction of Curiosity's outline, with the bottom squares illustrating the rover's [Rocker-bogie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocker-bogie) mounted wheels and the "T" on top representing the rover's [MastCam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiosity_(rover)#Mast_Camera_(MastCam)).

**Question:** Why does Curiosity have (at least) two images of itself on itself, or is one a QR-code?

[image: Curiosity Rover]

[image: Curiosity Rover]

Comment: According to JPL: The "augmented reality" or AR tag seen in the foreground can be used in the future with smart phones to obtain more information about the mission.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The right image is an [augmented reality tag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARTag), according to [NASA/JPL](http://spaceref.com/news/viewsr.html?pid=41594), and as commented by @aml.

Although early QR codes had fewer pixels than the ones seen nowadays, all have had black-white-black concentric "targets" at three corners.  Those can't fit into a 6x6 grid, not even the one-target [Micro QR](https://www.qrcode.com/en/codes/microqr.html) variant.

AR tags and QR tags are distinct.  They only overlap in their specifications and their uses: squareness and pointing cameras at them.

Comment: Thanks! A quick check of references in your first link (Wikipedia's AR Tag) shows that with all the error correction and removal of eight-fold ambiguity (rotation/mirror) those 36 bits only encode a number between 0 and 2047 if I understand correctly, but I'm not sure if reversing image value (positive/negative, light/dark) is used to get the top 1024 values or not.

Comment: @uhoh - it is definitely not a QR code