# Why are there different types of fiducial markers on Perseverance?

Tags: perseverance

I have noticed that there are different types of fiducial markers on Preseverance.

[image]

While I have seen the round markers on other rovers before, it is the first time that I see the rectengular markers. Of course this does not mean, that earlier rovers did not use them.

However, I wonder why there are different markers at all. I thought these markers would be used to calibrate the cameras, help to measure positions, orientations, distances, etc. But the rectengular markers look like AprilTags (are they?).

Do these different tags serve different purposes?

EDIT:

The picture is a screenshot from a NASA video I found on Twitter: https://twitter.com/NASA/status/1363940380346118144/video/1

Comment: Larger image at: https://mars.nasa.gov/resources/25618/navcam-panorama-of-the-perseverance-rovers-deck/

Comment: different but possibly related: [Why does Curiosity have two images of itself on itself, or is one a QR-code?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/38975/12102) and [Have “QR” or other 2D barcodes been used in spaceflight?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/31915/12102) and especially [What are the black and white circular patterns on the Curiosity rover?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/2985/12102)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the square ones seem to be Apriltags, series tag16h5, #27 and #28. There is a free iphone app that recognises these. Besides these two there are at least 4 other Apriltags visible in the original movie, though not at a resolution that allows their identities to be read.

Comment: Great answer and *Welcome to Space!* These are [AR tags](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARTag) per [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/38978/12102) but how can we be certain that they are fully compliant Apriltags? For example I can't tell the difference between 3. AprilTag and 4. ArUco in [this image](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Comparison_of_augmented_reality_fiducial_markers.svg). Also what does "series tag16h5, #27 and #28" mean? Is it possible to add some more supporting information and/or links to your already-very-interesting answer? *Thanks!*

Comment: See also the various examples of "Space AR" markers in answers to [Have “QR” or other 2D barcodes been used in spaceflight?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/31915/12102) Also wondering if these should be explained as "not actually [fiducial markers](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/2985/12102)" in your answer, or not (I just don't know).

Answer (score 0):

On the right side the codes we see is ARUCO code. Generally we use it for Distance calculation. This may be used for location identification for Drones installed on Rover.

Comment: Who is "we" in your answer?